# Copying innerHTML of each class to antoher div

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently struggling copying the innerHTML part of classes to another div. The problem is that I am using the same class name for every div but each div has another content. I want to achieve that based on a EventListener the innerHTML of the clicked div is copied to another div. So I basically want that If someone clicks on a emoji in div.emoji--select the same emoji is copied into div#text.  With my current JavaScript code my innerHTML ends up as undefined. I am currently trying to save each innerHTML of every div.emoji--select to an array and then use it in my function addEmoji().   I would highly appreciate your help. Please only plain JavaScript.

My HTML

```
<div id="text_wrapper">
  <div id="text" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>

</div>


<span class="emoji--select" ></span>
<span class="emoji--select"></span>
```

My JavaScript

```
//Select clicked emoji in div.emoji--select
var emojiText = []

var emojiSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('emoji--select')
for (var i = 0; i <= emojiSelect.length; i++) {
  emojiText.push(emojiSelect[i].innerHTML)

  emojiSelect[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    addEmoji(emojiText[i])
  })
}


//Add Emoji to div#text
function addEmoji(emojiSelected) {
  var text = document.getElementById('text')
  text.append(emojiSelected)

}
```

Comment: Where are your semicolons? That may be causing an issue but may also be just a formatting issue when you copied the code.

Comment: Instead of .append, try `text.text(text.text() + emojiSelected)` (and LOL at the syntax. Perhaps consider renaming the text variable.)

Comment: Hi zbkrt, did you see my answer. I think that is pretty clean and simple because there is no use of IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is one of context. The way your current code executes is that `i` exists in a parent scope of your loop from the anonymous event handler. When an event is handled, the handler looks at the nearest definition of `i`, which after the loop is completed, is 2.

To fix the scoping issue, you should use a self-invoking function to create a new shell for `i`.

```
for (var i = 0, len = emojiSelect.length; i < len; i++) {
  emojiText.push(emojiSelect[i].innerHTML);
  (function(i) {
      emojiSelect[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        addEmoji(emojiText[i]);
      });
  })(i);
}
```

Also note that I changed the the loop definition to store the array length and to iterate `i < len` instead of `i <= len`. You were looping one too many times.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! However somehow I had to move underneath the function(i)!  But now it works!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```js
var emojiText = []

var emojiSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('emoji--select');
for (var i = 0; i < emojiSelect.length; i++) {
  emojiText.push(emojiSelect[i].outerHTML)
  emojiSelect[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    addEmoji(this);
  })
}

function addEmoji(emojiSelected) {
  var elem = emojiSelected.cloneNode(true)
  text.append(elem);
}
```

```html
<div id="text_wrapper">
   <div id="text" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true">              </div>
</div>
<span class="emoji--select" ></span>
<span class="emoji--select"></span>
```